A supermartingale whose drift dominates variance must converge to $-\infty$ a.s.?
I am trying to fill in details of the second answer of this question:
https://mathoverflow.net/questions/55741/supermartingales-and-convergence.
The answer claims the following statement: let $\{X_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a supermartingale. Decompose $X_n$ into $M_n+Y_n$ with $M_n$ a martingale and $Y_n$ predictable. Let $\mu_t=E[X_t]$ and $\sigma_t^2=\sum_{s=1}^t E[(M_s-M_{s-1})^2|M_0,\dots,M_{s-1}]$, then $X_n\to -\infty$ a.s. if $\sigma_t=o(|u_t|)$. The answer suggests this claim follows the martingale central limit theorem.
I consider a simpler case with assumptions that $\mu_t\leq -c t$ and $E[(M_s-M_{s-1})^2|M_0,\dots,M_{s-1}]<b$ with $c,b>0$ be constant.
Let $\tau(n)=\inf\{t|\sigma_t^2\geq n\}$ and assuming $\sigma_t^2\to +\infty$ a.s. Applying the martingale CLT,  $\frac{M_{\tau(n)}}{\sqrt{n}}\to N(0,1)$ in distribution. Therefore, the stopped supermartingale $X_{\tau(n)}$ is roughly normal with mean $\mu_{\tau(n)}\leq -c\tau(n)\leq -\frac{c}{b}n$ and variance $n$. Using Borel-Cantelli's lemma, we can show $X_{\tau(n)}$ does converge to $-\infty$.
The convergence of $X_{\tau(n)}$ isn't sufficient for that $X_n$ almost surely converges to $-\infty$. We could always take a random walk $\{W_n\}$ satisfying that $-\infty=\liminf W_n\leq \limsup W_n=+\infty$ and define $W_{\nu(n)}$ with $\nu(n)=\inf\{t>\nu(n-1)|W_n\leq -n\}$. Then  $W_{\nu(n)}\to -\infty$ a.s.
So here is my question: to apply the martingale CLT, I must work with $X_{\tau(n)}$. There is no control of $X_t(\omega)$ on $\tau(n)<t<\tau(n+1)$. How could I conclude $X_t\to -\infty$ a.s.?
Is there something I miss?
